# How do I switch the direction of the Torus uncoiling?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry

[image][image]

Notice how from the centre the Torus uncoils.
It starts from tight coils and ends in loose coils.
I want it to start with the loose and then end in the tight coils.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi.  It would be helpful if you could share a screenshot from your _Operator Panel_ from when you created the object (I'm guessing Curve Spirals > Torus ) so that we could more easily recreate your spiral in order to try and find a solution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information on how you created the object.